# How to repeat the table row for 12 times on page load in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i just have the html but have no idea that how could i repeat just table body row for 12 times through jquery.

i just have the html but i have no idea that how to row the table for 12 times

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="table_body">
<tr id="table_body_row">
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Mark</td>
 <td>Otto</td>
 <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines should get you there:

```
var row = $("tr#table_body_row");
var tbody = $("tbody#table_body");

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    tbody.append(row);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you a rendering data dynamically and i am demonstrating you by rendering 12 list of countries.
Data:

```
var object = [{
id: 1,
name: "Andorra",
geography: "-2147483648",
standardTimezone: "0"
}, {
id: 2,
name: "United Arab Emirates",
geography: "-2147397248",
standardTimezone: "0"
}, {
id: 3,
name: "Afghanistan",
geography: "-733881600",
standardTimezone: "3600"
}, {
id: 4,
name: "Antigua and Barbuda",
geography: "481078800",
standardTimezone: "7200"
}, {
id: 5,
name: "Anguilla",
geography: "496803600",
standardTimezone: "3600"
}, {
id: 6,
name: "Albania",
geography: "512528400",
standardTimezone: "7200"
}, {
id: 7,
name: "Armenia",
geography: "528253200",
standardTimezone: "3600"
}, {
id: 8,
name: "Netherlands Antilles",
geography: "543978000",
standardTimezone: "7200"
}, {
id: 9,
name: "Angola",
geography: "559702800",
standardTimezone: "3600"
}, {
id: 10,
name: "Antarctica",
geography: "575427600",
standardTimezone: "7200"
}, {
id: 11,
name: "Argentina",
geography: "591152400",
standardTimezone: "3600"
}, {
id: 12,
name: "American Samoa",
geography: "606877200",
standardTimezone: "7200"
}];
```

You HTML would be:

```
<body>
<table id="countryTable">
<thead>
  <th>Country Name</th>
  <th>Geography</th>
  <th>Time Zone</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

JS would be :

```
$.each(object, function(index, data) {
var tbody = $("#countryTable > tbody");
var tr = $("<tr>");
tr.append($("<td>", {
'text': data.name
}));
tr.append($("<td>", {
'text': data.geography
}));
tr.append($("<td>", {
'text': data.standardTimezone
}));
tbody.append(tr);
});
```

Working Fiddle Rendering 12 rows dynamically can be checked here [Rendering Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teka0ous/)

This is the exact and easiest solution for you problem